# How does pandas use a Series object to slice a Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a 6x4 pandas Data Frame filled with random numbers from the standard normal distribution (index is numbers 0 to 5, and columns 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D'.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=[0,1,2,3,4,5], columns=list('ABCD))
```

Looks like this:
[image: Data Frame]

I add a column with some strings:

```
df['E'] = ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'three']
```

Now the Data Frame looks like this:
[image]

Referencing column E, I can obtain only rows with the keywords 'one' or 'four':

```
x = df['E'].isin(['one','four'])
df[x]
```

I get this:
[image]

But when i check the type of x, it's a pandas Series (pandas.core.series.Series).

I don't understand how a Series is interpreted to slice the Data Frame? I'd like to understand on somewhat of a fundamental level. How does it know what rows to return? If I print x, it's a Series filled with booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Boolean indexing. Simple way to understand, the Boolean values are aligned with data frame. Wherever the Boolean series is true, the row is picked up. Otherwise (false), the row is dropped. For instance, x has true at index 0,1,4, so the data frame rows with these indices are picked up, i.e., the first, second and fifth rows in your case.